# The same query on the same MySQL database take different time to be executed

Tags: php, mysql, forum, phpbb

I have a PhpBB board with about 3000 users and 500.000 posts. On the last days I notice that some topics uses long time to opened than the standard (about 2 seconds instead 0.05 seconds).
So I made a debug to investigate and I see that it's a query fault. It's the same query that take different time to be executed, depending on the topic that it goes to request. 
For example this query take 1.7011 seconds to be executed:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, u.user_active, u.user_mask, u.user_color, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, u.user_posts, u.user_from, u.user_long, u.user_lat, u.user_from_flag, u.user_website, u.user_email, u.user_aim, u.user_facebook, u.user_flickr, u.user_googleplus, u.user_icq, u.user_jabber, u.user_linkedin, u.user_msnm, u.user_skype, u.user_twitter, u.user_yim, u.user_youtube, u.user_regdate, u.user_allow_viewemail, u.user_rank, u.user_rank2, u.user_rank3, u.user_rank4, u.user_rank5, u.user_sig, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type, u.user_allowavatar, u.user_allowsmile, u.user_allow_viewonline, u.user_session_time, u.user_warnings, u.user_level, u.user_birthday, u.user_next_birthday_greeting, u.user_gender, u.user_personal_pics_count, u.user_style, u.user_lang, u.preferenza_meteo, u.stazione_meteo, u.ct_miserable_user, p.*, t.topic_poster, t.title_compl_infos
FROM phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u, phpbb_topics t
WHERE p.topic_id = 17278
AND t.topic_id = p.topic_id
AND u.user_id = p.poster_id
ORDER BY p.post_time ASC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

This is the EXPLAIN result:
[image]

This query, that it's the same, but it using a different ID topic in WHERE clause, take 0.0015 seconds, that was the normal time for this kind of DB request.

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, u.user_active, u.user_mask, u.user_color, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, u.user_posts, u.user_from, u.user_long, u.user_lat, u.user_from_flag, u.user_website, u.user_email, u.user_aim, u.user_facebook, u.user_flickr, u.user_googleplus, u.user_icq, u.user_jabber, u.user_linkedin, u.user_msnm, u.user_skype, u.user_twitter, u.user_yim, u.user_youtube, u.user_regdate, u.user_allow_viewemail, u.user_rank, u.user_rank2, u.user_rank3, u.user_rank4, u.user_rank5, u.user_sig, u.user_avatar, u.user_avatar_type, u.user_allowavatar, u.user_allowsmile, u.user_allow_viewonline, u.user_session_time, u.user_warnings, u.user_level, u.user_birthday, u.user_next_birthday_greeting, u.user_gender, u.user_personal_pics_count, u.user_style, u.user_lang, u.preferenza_meteo, u.stazione_meteo, u.ct_miserable_user, p.*, t.topic_poster, t.title_compl_infos
FROM phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u, phpbb_topics t
WHERE p.topic_id = 17250
AND t.topic_id = p.topic_id
AND u.user_id = p.poster_id
ORDER BY p.post_time ASC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

This is the EXPLAIN result for this query:
[image]

I use this board since about 15 years, and I never had notice similar problem, and similar timings to open a topic. But I'm not able to understand where the problem could be.

Comment: It could be your index size has grown to the point where it no longer fits in memory. On some versions of MySQL that makes performance drop off a cliff.

Comment: Consider ANALYZE each of the 3 tables and try again. Index statistics may need to be refreshed. Are all tables innodb?

Comment: @WilsonHauck no, all tables are MyISAM. ANALYZE command on that 3 tables does not return errors.

Comment: Now that index statistics have been refreshed with Analyze, What is the time required for each of the 2 queries?

Comment: The same of before... one slow and the other quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (I hope) converting the phpbb_posts table in INNODB instead MyISAM. I don't know if this is the best solution, but now all query run quicklyand using the right KEY INDEX.

The first query I posted on first post, that before previously took 1.7011 seconds to be executed, now require only 0.0017 seconds.

This is the EXPLAIN result:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses internal caches to process your requests. More frequent parts of the database are in the caches while others are not. Executing the same query multiple times should show you, that the first call is, as far as the query and the result is not in cache, the slowest and consecutive calls getting faster. Changes to the database invalidates the caches, so it may be, that your query become slow for the next call again.

Second point are the joins. The more data is required to match, the longer the query will run. You can see this on your explains in the "rows" column. Your first query will explore 1004 lines of table "p" while the second has only 476.

Comment: as @tadman says there could be a lack of memory to the caches. When your server has enough resources you could increase them to fit your database. Other way is, that you archive some data and reduce the number of posts/threads. Archiving is not required to remove the data, but reduce the size of your primary table that should be in the cache. The archive could also be read, but should be uncached and slow. But i dont know of PHPBB has such a feature.

Comment: I will investigate about the cache memory, because I don't think it's a simply cache problem, because the same topic need the same time even after some calls, and even without new posts adding that coulds invalidates the caches.

About second point, I obtain long times even with minor rows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNWRz.png

Comment: the thing that I notice, is that on slow queries, the KEY INDEX used is different. Try to check on the images the KEY column.

Comment: Yes, the mysql optimizer detects, that this key should be the best for the query. It depends on the data size expected in your table. You are using 3 fields from table p in the query, so one possible solution could be to create an index that matches better and could be used for 2 or maybe all fields. But be careful: creating a new index increase the size of the index memory and the write time to the table.